# How can I count the number of fields with similar value

Tags: mysql

I have got many words that repeat themselves a lot in the database,.. i need to know how much each word has repeated itself.. I tried different queries..

```
    SELECT word_name,SUM(`word_name`) AS word_count
FROM `words` 
WHERE `search_id`=5 
GROUP BY word_count
```

But it doesnt work..it gives me: #1056 - Can't group on 'word_count'

Okay, I found a way:

```
  SELECT word_name,COUNT(`tweet_id`) AS word_count
FROM `words` 
WHERE `search_id`=5 
GROUP BY word_name
```

lol..now need to order the whole thing.. whats the best way to do it..is it to put in a subquery?

Comment: what is the schema of your table?

Comment: word_name and thats about it...a primary key too

Comment: what are you trying to `order by`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to `count()` the number of similar `word_name`:

```
SELECT count(`word_name`) AS word_count, `word_name` 
FROM `words` 
WHERE `search_id`=5 
GROUP BY `word_name`
ORDER BY word_count
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8130/2)

I would add `word_name`  to the final result so you know which count is associated to each word

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd yes you can -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8130/3 -- you can use an alias in a `ORDER BY` not a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SUM()` try `COUNT()`.

Also add `GROUP BY word_name` before `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 SELECT count(`word_name`) AS word_count, `word_name` 
FROM `words` 
WHERE `search_id`=5 
GROUP BY `word_name`
 ORDER BY word_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT word_name,count(`word_name`) AS word_count
FROM `words` 
WHERE `search_id`=5 
GROUP BY count(`word_name`)
```

You cannot use alias in GROUP BY or WHERE clause except they are in a SUB-QUERY

Comment: #1111 - Invalid use of group function